# How to replace lines of a table with jQuery / AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a html table with following structure

```
<table class="mytable">
   <tbody class="body">
      <tr class="headline1"> ... several td tags with some text ... </tr>
      <tr class="headline2"> ... several td tags with some text ... </tr>
      <tr class="content"> ... several td tags with some text ... </tr>
      <tr class="content"> ... several td tags with some text ... </tr>
      <tr class="content"> ... several td tags with some text ... </tr>
      <tr class="content"> ... several td tags with some text ... </tr>
      <tr class="sum"> ... several td tags with some text ... </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The structure of the table cannot be changed. Now I want to replace the lines (`<tr>` elements) with class "content" and "sum" with the result of an ajax call (search.php generates the same table structure like described before)

My current code looks like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        const search_field = $('#search_field');

        search_field.keyup(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://someurl/search.php?search=' + search_field.val(),
                type:"POST",
                success:function(data){
                    var xxx = $(data).find('.body').html();
                    $('.body').html(xxx);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The code works but replaces the whole tbody. I would like to replace only the `<tr>` elements (with all `<td>` elements included in the `<tr>` element). So the two headlines should be kept and not taken from the result of the ajax call.

An easy solution would be to close the `<tbody>`element after the headlines and create a new `<tbody>`element with a different id/class. But as already mentioned this is not possible because I cannot change the structure of the table

Comment: The content of every line is very complex and consists of a lot of data. Using JSON is no option for my use case. Therefore I'm looking for a solution to replace the lines in the table with the HTML code provided by the server

Comment: OK, I understand it now. Somehow I missed the obvious - that you only want to replace the `.content` rows. Anyways, rethink about the JSON suggestion. Create an API instead that server JSON data, not HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cache your `.sum` row
- Remove old `.content` rows
- Grab only the `.content` from the new data HTML
- Use the `.before()` method to insert the new rows **before** your `.sum` element row
- Use the `.on()` method on your Search input. A use could as well paste a value into it, in which case the *key* events will not register

```js
const updateTableContent = (data) => {
  const $content = $(".mytable .body .content");
  const $sum = $(".mytable .body .sum");

  // 1. remove old .content rows
  $content.remove();
  
  // 2. append new .content rows right before .sum row
  $sum.before($(data).find(".content"));
};

// Example:

// Just a demo response data mockup:
const data = `<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><title>Test</title>
</head><body><table class="mytable"><tbody class="body">
  <tr class="headline1"><td>Headline new 1</td></tr>
  <tr class="headline2"><td>Headline new 2</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 1</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 2</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 3</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 4</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 5</td></tr>
  <tr class="sum"><td>Sum new</td></tr>
</tbody></table></body></html>`;

$('#search_field').on("input", function() {
  // AJAX...
      updateTableContent(data);
  //...
});
```

```html
<label>Search: <input id="search_field" type="search"></label>
<table class="mytable">
   <tbody class="body">
      <tr class="headline1"><td>Headline old 1</td></tr>
      <tr class="headline2"><td>Headline old 2</td></tr>
      <tr class="content"><td>Content old 1</td></tr>
      <tr class="content"><td>Content old 2</td></tr>
      <tr class="content"><td>Content old 3</td></tr>
      <tr class="sum"><td>Sum old</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Tip: nowadays, you don't necessarily need jQuery:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);


// Task: Search fetch data:

const updateTableContent = (data) => {
  const elsContent = els(".mytable .body .content");
  const elSum = el(".mytable .body .sum");

  // 1. remove old .content rows
  elsContent.forEach(elCont => elCont.remove());
  
  // 2. append new .content rows right before .sum row
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html");
  const elsContentNew = els(".content", doc);
  elSum.before(...elsContentNew);
};

// Example:

// Just a demo response data mockup:
const data = `<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><title>Test</title>
</head><body><table class="mytable"><tbody class="body">
  <tr class="headline1"><td>Headline new 1</td></tr>
  <tr class="headline2"><td>Headline new 2</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 1</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 2</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 3</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 4</td></tr>
  <tr class="content"><td>Content new 5</td></tr>
  <tr class="sum"><td>Sum new</td></tr>
</tbody></table></body></html>`;

const elSearch = el('#search_field');
elSearch.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const value = elSearch.value.trim();
  //fetch(`https://someurl/search.php?search=${value}`)
  //      .then(res => res.text())
  //      .then(updateTableContent);
  
  // DEMO WITH MOCKUP:
  updateTableContent(data);
});
```

```html
<label>Search: <input id="search_field" type="search"></label>
<table class="mytable">
   <tbody class="body">
      <tr class="headline1"><td>Headline old 1</td></tr>
      <tr class="headline2"><td>Headline old 2</td></tr>
      <tr class="content"><td>Content old 1</td></tr>
      <tr class="content"><td>Content old 2</td></tr>
      <tr class="content"><td>Content old 3</td></tr>
      <tr class="sum"><td>Sum old</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Anyways, if possible, your `search.php` should be better rewritten to serve JSON data. Such data can be reused within many other components that do not necessarily use `<table>`. Also, you don't necessarily need to use such JSON data from the frontend, but also from other backend scripts. Think about it, a rewrite of your server-side API logic could be helpful on the long run.

Answer (score -1):

```
...
success: function(data) {
$('.content:eq(0)').html( $(data).find('.content:eq(0)').html() );
$('.content:eq(1)').html( $(data).find('.content:eq(1)').html() );
$('.content:eq(2)').html( $(data).find('.content:eq(2)').html() );
$('.content:eq(3)').html( $(data).find('.content:eq(3)').html() );
$('.sum').html($(data).find('.sum').html());
}
```

Or using a loop for .content rows:

```
success: function(data) {
let rows = $('.body .content');
for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let selector = '.body .content:eq(' + i + ')'
    $(selector).html( $(data).find(selector).html() );
}
}
```